# Contextily map upside down when used with cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy, openmaptiles, contextily

When a [contextily](https://pypi.org/project/contextily/) basemap is added to an axis projected with [cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/), the map appears **upside down**. Here is a minimum example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import contextily

# contextily & cartopy
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.Mercator())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
ax.set_extent([-11,37,35,70])
contextily.add_basemap(ax)
```

The following code produces a correct map, however, without cartopy features:

```
# contextily
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-1163881, 4068715)
ax.set_ylim( 4118821,11118821)
contextily.add_basemap(ax)
```

It looks like there is some projection issue with the cartopy coordinate system. How to add a proper basemap to a cartopy plot?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well... not sure how to resolve this with contextily, but found a solution using the built in cartopy method `ax.add_wmts()` to access and plot basemap tiles.

```
url = 'http://map1c.vis.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts-geo/wmts.cgi'
layer_name = 'BlueMarble_ShadedRelief_Bathymetry'

ax.add_wmts(url, layer_name, alpha = 0.9)
```

Additional layers can be found [here](https://wiki.earthdata.nasa.gov/display/GIBS/GIBS+Available+Imagery+Products#expand-ReferenceLayers9Layers). Just need to swap out the `layer_name`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great solution, as it also allows to download actual satellite data products of environmental variables. Note that it only works with `owslib 0.19.2` or above.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the latest version of contextily (1.0.0) and cartopy (0.18.0), as for me it is working fine then:

Using your exact code, with cartopy and contextily:

[image]

Using

```
>>> contextily.__version__                                                                                                                                                                                     
'1.0.0'

>>> cartopy.__version__                                                                                                                                                                                        
'0.18.0'
```